# Bash - sed explanation of expression

Tags: bash, sed

This command gives me result which i want

```
ps -eo %cpu,pid |sort -r | head | sed 's/[ ]\+/ /g'

%CPU PID
0.8 867
0.8 785
0.8 6095
0.8 543
0.8 479
0.0 978
0.0 975
0.0 974
0.0 962
```

But i don't understand why `\+` in sed. I know for what + stands, but why `\`?
Can someone give me proper explanation please.

Thank you.

Comment: Look up backslash escaping.

Comment: It is the same as `sed -e 's/[ ]+/ /g'`.

Comment: Which is essentially same as `tr -s " "`

Comment: @fedorqui: Not in my version of sed (GNU sed 4.2.2).

Comment: @anubhava wow. Beautiful solution! I miss -s option in tr command. Thanx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backslash tells `sed` to interpret the `+` as a special character, which you probably know means "one or more occurrences". Without it, the `+` is taken as a literal. That's just the syntax of `sed`.